# plot values from bidemensionnal arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have got a bidimensionnal array containing values that I would like to plot on the Y axis, and a bidimensionnal array, of datetime values that I would like to plot in the X axis, and I would like to get two lines of values against date from those arrays.
But these structures used as-is don't work as expected, as I have got a different kind of graph than a line graph.

Values for the x axis (dates):

```
    [[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 1, 0, 0, 57, 386000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 1, 0, 0, 59, 579000), datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 1, 0, 0, 27, 676000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 1, 0, 0, 26, 414000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 1, 0, 0, 28, 145000), datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, 26, 432000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 1, 0, 0, 27, 301000), datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 1, 0, 0, 27, 643000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 1, 0, 0, 27, 673000), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0, 28, 294000)], 
[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 1, 0, 0, 57, 386000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 1, 0, 0, 59, 579000), datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 1, 0, 0, 27, 676000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 0, 0, 25, 135000), datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 1, 0, 0, 26, 414000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 1, 0, 0, 28, 145000), datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0, 26, 432000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 1, 0, 0, 27, 301000), datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 1, 0, 0, 27, 643000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 1, 0, 0, 27, 673000), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0, 28, 294000)]]
```

Values for the y axis (min, max):

```
    [[-8.0, 19.0, 11.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], 
[-12.0, -7.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -7.0, -7.0]]
```

I would like some help on how to transform these structures so that two lines of min and max over date are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two "bidimensional" arrays, called `x` and `y`, which have the same length, then try

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# populate x and y arrays.

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x[:,0], y[:,0], 'g-o')
ax.plot(x[:,1], y[:,1], 'r-x')
```

In general, if your arrays have only 1 dimension, you could simply do

```
ax.plot(x, y)
```

If your arrays have more than two sets of values, you could do

```
for i in range(x.shape[-1]):
    ax.plot(x[:,i], y[:,0])
```

The notation `x[:,n]` has two parts; the `:` means to take data from every row and the `,n` means to take the `n+1` (0 represents first) element from each row. This works because your data is structured like

```
[[date00, date01],
 [date10, date11],
 [date20, date21],
 ...
 [dateN0, dateN1]]
```

so `x[:,0]` takes the first column and `x[:,1]` takes the second column.

If you had a large array of many dimensions, you can index each array like `x[dim0, dim1, ..., dimN]`. For example, say you had a 3 dimensional array of medical data where the dimensions represented patientID, sampleID, viral_load, you could grab the last viral load number from all samples from the first patient by doing `data[0, :, -1]`, or all the viral load numbers from all samples from that patient by doing `data[0, :, :]`.

Comment: Allright thank you.  Is there a more generic way of doing it so that it would work for array of array of dimension superior to 2 or even of dimension 1 ?  I tried in a loop but it just plot a straight vertical line on the graph.